# Check if all three different values are present within the group

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a 5 records:

```
id |usuario_id|   key 
-----------------------
1  |    1     | pink
2  |    1     | red
3  |    1     | blue
4  |    1     | yellow
5  |    3     | pink
```

My question is as follows:

How can I retrieve `usuario_id`s that have all three `key`s: pink,red and blue.

Comment: Are you trying to query the db for the values pink, red, or blue?

Comment: That is not a question. What is your desired result?

Comment: check a answer for @suslov is great answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if there are all three unique `key`s within each `usuario_id` entry in the `having` clause:

```
select `usuario_id`
from `tbl`
where `key` in ('pink', 'red', 'blue')
group by `usuario_id`
having count(distinct `key`) = 3
```

*ActiveRecord* query:

```
Tbl.select(:usuario_id)
   .where(key: %w(pink red blue))
   .group_by(:usuario_id)
   .having('count(distinct `usuario_id`) = 3')
```